# HTML tags not stored in grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

In grocery crud I am trying to store text content in database. Everything working fine. But the HTML tags are eliminated automatically.

Eg. If the text is as below

> welcome to stack overflow.<br />Grocery CRUD is an auto PHP Codeigniter
>   CRUD generator.

Then in database it is stored as

> welcome to stack overflow.Grocery CRUD is an auto PHP Codeigniter
>   CRUD generator.

Comment: The information is too limited. Could you provide more information, like database function, using PDO, or MYSQLi, do you use framework or not? Because sometimes when you use framework, that means the framework clean the request, that cause the HTML tag to dissapear.

Comment: its codeigniter

Comment: It could be the CI cleaner. You should seek the CI Documentation about it :) There's a CI Problem on old thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999441/codeigniter-remove-all-html-tags

Comment: Thanks for your comment. there is no input.php in the directory system/libraries/

Comment: Yes, because it's old CI engine, I said you should look into CI cleaning. Especially when you use builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next.

```
$insert_data = mysql_real_escape_string("welcome to stack overflow.<br />Grocery CRUD is an auto PHP Codeigniter CRUD generator.");
```

This take all the sentence as a string.

Comment: can't find the file in codeigniter framework,on which to  place this line

Answer (score 0):

What's the datatype of that particular field in MySQL? From what I'm aware, to make content safe, Grocery CRUD will strip off any HTML tags if it's a normal input. Hence, to store content with HTML tag.

- Update the datatype of your MySQL column to "TEXT".
- Use a HTML editor, like the built-in CK Editor. Under application/config/grocery_crud.php : `$config['grocery_crud_default_text_editor'] = 'ckeditor';`

Hope that it works

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old question, but I face it right now.
Make sure that config `grocery_crud_xss_clean` is set to `false`.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28916371)

Comment: I wanna say that "grocery_crud_xss_clean" = true triggers php strip_tags() function and setting it to false solved my problem and html tags appeared in db after save changes